# No internet,Dns resolution problem?

Tags: internet, dns

I've tried the solutions posted in other threads but have had no success.
I have a problem with my Pi not connecting to the internet so far I've tried wired and wireless on my home network and wireless to a mobile hotspot, it connects to all the network but I get a DNS resolution issue in the browser window whenever I try a website.

I can ssh the pi, outputs of various commands as follows:

Version:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/*-release | grep VERSIOON=

VERSION="10 (buster)"
```

Release:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

ifconfig:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.20.215  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.20.255
        inet6 fe80::6963:db0:843:ff9d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:cf:ec:6c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1423  bytes 227835 (222.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1003  bytes 133921 (130.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 19178  bytes 1736822 (1.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19178  bytes 1736822 (1.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.20.210  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.20.255
        inet6 fe80::b4d5:cefa:6cf1:daed  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:6a:0a:97:62:6e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1384  bytes 357017 (348.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 12  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 153  bytes 22207 (21.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Ping:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=65.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=65.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=65.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=65.6 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 7ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 65.090/65.335/65.568/0.181 ms
pi@raspberrypi:~
```

IP addr show:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:cf:ec:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.20.215/24 brd 192.168.20.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6963:db0:843:ff9d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:6a:0a:97:62:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.20.210/24 brd 192.168.20.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b4d5:cefa:6cf1:daed/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

IP route show:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip route show
default via 192.168.20.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.20.215 metric 202
default via 192.168.20.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.20.210 metric 303
192.168.20.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.20.215 metric 202
192.168.20.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.20.210 metric 303
```

resolv.conf:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1


search pihole1
```

Comment: Do you or did you use pihole? (see reference in resolv.conf)

Comment: yes.actually i accidently installed pihole on the pi that isn't working-i mixed up the ip's,when i realised this i unistalled it and reinstalled on the correct pi, i'm wondering if inadvertantly uninstalled something necessary for dns?

Comment: just prepend `#` before `search pihole1'` for comment the line by doing `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`. Disconnect your Internet connexion (wlan0 or eth0) , try again to reconnect. If don't work put `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf`, but uninstall pihole if it has nothing to do there.

Comment: no success with either option unfortunately,after each restart resolv.conf  gets overwritten back to the original configuration

Comment: Looks like perhaps pihole dorked your resolvconf.conf settings? Have a look at /etc/resolvconf.conf, especially the name_servers line. Make it the IP of your DNS server (router?). This whole resolv.conf thing is twitchy, especially when mucked by software that doesn't clean up properly on removal.

Comment: no luck,heres the output of that file-'# Configuration for resolvconf(8)
# See resolvconf.conf(5) for details

resolv_conf=/etc/resolv.conf
# If you run a local name server, you should uncomment the below line and
# configure your subscribers configuration files below.
#name_servers=192.168.20.1

# Mirror the Debian package defaults for the below resolvers
# so that resolvconf integrates seemlessly.
dnsmasq_resolv=/var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf
pdnsd_conf=/etc/pdnsd.conf
unbound_conf=/var/cache/unbound/resolvconf_resolvers.conf'

Comment: pihole installs (I think) dnsmasq. Did that get removed? If not, you should remove that. Then you could try 'dpkg-reconfigure dhcpcd5' to try to get things back to normal. Also, what is the output of 'ls -l /etc/resolv.conf'?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Dec  7 12:33 /etc/resolv.conf -> /etc/resolvconf/run/resolv.conf

Comment: What happens if you 'sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.link' and then reboot?

Comment: nothing,still the same

Comment: @mrdenmark1: And after you do the 'sudo mv' and reboot, what is the output of 'ls -l /etc/resolv.conf' and what is the contents of /etc/resolv.conf'? Also, are you using dhcpcd5, systemd-networkd, or NetworkManager?

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mv
mv: missing file operand
Try 'mv --help' for more information.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
ls: cannot access '/etc/resolv.conf': No such file or directory

Comment: and what is the contents of /etc/resolv.conf'?-it doesn't appear to exist,a new file prompt appears at the bottom of the nano screen,the other 3 options i'm unsure about-i havn't purposesly enabled or installed any of those 3 options

Comment: iv'e just looked in the /etc/ folder and i have a resolvconf.lin resolvconf.bak resolvconf.new and resolvconf.conf but no resolv.conf.there was one when i satrted this thread as i copied the output above,i guess one of the commands iv'e followed here has removed it?

Comment: Also, are you using dhcpcd5, systemd-networkd, or NetworkManager? If you do 'ps aux | grep dhcp\|systemd-networkd' do you see dhcpcd or systemd-networkd?

Comment: this is the output-pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps aux | grep dhcp\|systemd-networkd
pi       28084  0.0  0.0   7348   548 pts/0    S+   16:18   0:00 grep --color=auto dhcp|systemd-networkd

Comment: @mrdenmark1, so neither dhcpcd or systemd-networkd are running...did you install Network Manager? Frankly, my advice is that the whole resolvconf/resolv.conf thing is pretty fragile, and once one of dhcpcd/systemd-networkd/NetworkManager has had their fingers into it, it's not easy to get back to a known working state, so rebuilding your SD Card might be a much more expedient approach.

Comment: ok,thanks for all your time and effort,thats what i'll do.i have made a backup of the sd card if anyone feels like its an itch they need to scratch!

Answer (score 0):

I've read the comments. It's kind of silly solution, however, follow the instructions:
1. `nano /etc/resolv.conf.new`
add these lines and save the file:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.2.2.4
```

Then, add this line in "/etc/rc.local":
`cp /etc/resolv.conf.new /etc/resolv.conf`

Reboot the device and check it out.

Comment: @m rostami, didn't fix it unfortunately

Comment: tell me the result of thess commands: `traceroute www.google.com` and `sudo service dnsmasq status`

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ traceroute www.google.com
www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `www.google.com' on position 1 (argc 1)

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service dnsmasq status
Unit dnsmasq.service could not be found.

Comment: And what about: `cat /etc/hosts`

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       raspberrypi

Comment: It is really not a good idea to always overwrite the dynamic settings in `/etc/resolv.conf` from the resolver. There is a note given in that file. If you want a static resolv.conf then just disable the resolver by inserting a line `resolvconf=NO` in `/etc/resolvconf.conf`.